# Problems connecting via ssh from windows / wsl

Tags: networking, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

## Setup

- Banana Pi m2U running raspbian, (`uname -r` gives "3.10.108-BPI-M2U-Kernel")
- ssh server running on said bPi (atteched ssh config bellow), listening on port 22, allowing only public key authentication with a few select keys
- windows 10 laptop with wsl2 running `Ubuntu 21.10` (and uname gives `5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2`)
- router provided by ISP, port 22 of the bPi is forwarded to external port 2222
- duckdns dynamic dns, updated by a program on the bPi (to my knowledge also doing ipv4 and ipv6)

## What does / does not work

I've tried the following scenarios to connect to the bPi:

- Connecting from my WSL instance to the local ip and port 22 of the bPi works.
- Connecting from my WSL instance to the public ip or dynamic dns and port 2222 of the router **does not work**, exact details provided bellow
- Connecting from my windows instance (using either the ssh command from powershell or putty) to the public ip or dynamic dns address and port 2222 **does not work (hang/timeout)**
- Connecting from my windows instance (using either the ssh command from powershell or putty) to the local ip and port 22 does work
- Connecting from my friend's native Ubuntu installation to the public ip or dynamic dns and port 2222 works.
- Connecting from the bPi to the public ip or hostname and port 2222 also works.

## Goal

The goal would obviously be to be able to connect from my PC to the public hostname/port of the bPi so I can access it from outside of my home network.

### Past

Important: all of the scenarios (including the ones not working) have **already worked before**, but for some reason some of them stopped working some time (< two months) ago. I'm not sure if anything got updated, but that is certainly possible.

### Suspected causes

The last two scenarios suggest that the problem is not with the router or the rPi, but with my PC's setup of WSL2 on windows10.

### Exact error details

When running `ssh -v -v -v -p 2222 pi@hostname` on either powershell or wsl, I get a normal log until `debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent`, where it hangs for some time, then exit with `debug3: recv - from CB ERROR:10060, io:00000229C830EF10 \ ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to <IP> port 2222: Connection timed out`

## Search / found answers

I've already tried to search "debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent" and "ssh only works locally", but did not find any working solutions.

Most of the answers was fixing problems preventing **any** connection from anywhere.

One of the reuccurring themes was wrong MTU settings. I did try to lower my client's MTU in WSL (not sure if that is respected via Windows) to 1000 or bellow but that did not help at all. I could not set mtu on the bPi, as it reported "Device or resource busy", but since it's already working with others I don't think the problem is with the bPi or the router.

### Additional details

Attached ssh settings (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`):

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
PermitTunnel yes
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

If requested, I can also make packet captures with wireshark.

Comment: Would it be more accurate for the title to say "from Windows host", since it seems to be failing from *both* Windows (putty/powershell) and WSL?

Comment: Is there any chance that (a) the router itself is running ssh on 2022, (b) the router is configured to only accept ssh connections internally? Or that (c) there's any chance the router is forwarding the internal connection to another device than it does for external connections?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds A) afaik, no. I nmapped the external IP and only found my port open, even when I changed it from 2222 to something else. On the internal IP it has port 53, 80, 443 and 5060 open.
B) I don't see any such setting on the routers admin panel, but I might be missing it, or it could be a hidden one.
C) afaik no. I disabled all other port forward rules

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds also, I think any of the described problems would block all external connections, not just mine, i.e. my friends would also be unable to connect.

Comment: Well, not quite - But that's my fault for not being clear that (a)/(b) was supposed to be an "and" scenario.  If it ran an SSH server for internal connections on port 2022, but forwarded external connections to the PI, then that *might* have explained it.  BUT, I do agree that you have ruled that out with the mapping.

Comment: Second thought - Just a curiosity check -- If you change the Pi sshd config to allow password authentication, can you get further into the login process?  I'm not recommending that you actually log in via password; just see if it's then allowed.

Comment: Also might compare `ssh-keyscan`'s from/to the various connection endpoints.  I think they'll match.  Also, what type of key?  RSA?  EDCDSA?  ED25519?